# Grails create the mysql table during startup

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to create the sample table data during start-up. I have the below code in my `BootStrap.groovy` file.

But `Sql.newInstance` giving the exception.

how can I run the `mysqldump` script during startup?

```
println "developmnet creating table"

String sqlString = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/data/table_dump.sql").text

def db = [url:grailsApplication.config.dataSource.url, user:grailsApplication.config.dataSource.username, password:grailsApplication.config.dataSource.password, driver:grailsApplication.config.dataSource.driverClassName]

println "DataBase"+ db

def cls = Class.forName(db.driver).newInstance();
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

sql.execute(sqlString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at [Grails Database Migration Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration). It provides a good approach to manage migration scripts and database state management.